# How to give Edm.time type in URL of abap gateway?

Tags: url, abap, gateway

how to pass type `edm.time` in URL for `ABAP` gateway?
My URL looks like `.../EmployeeName='abc'&TimeIn='...'`

I have tried `'11:11:11'`, `'11.11.11'` ,`'PT11H00M00S'`, '`111211`'.
None of them are working.

Answer (score 1):

`PT11H00M00S` should be the right form.

I think the syntax of your url is wrong.

Try it with 
`/ZEmployeeSet(EmployeeName='abc',TimeIn='PT11H00M00S',...)`