# How to send EDM.TIME as a parameter in HTTP GET request

Tags: http, odata, http-get, sap-gateway

Can't find how to send edm.time as a parameter in get request in an url.
Tried many variations but with no luck.

I think it has to do maybe with character escaping but it didn't work for me either, I'm probably missing out something.

For example, I tried:

`http::<some_url>/some_func?time=time120000`

EDIT 1:

I tried the example from the other thread posted here and it also doesn't work: `/func(time=‘PT11H00M00S’)`. this raises an error.

EDIT 2:

I'm trying to pass this edm.time to a function import.
dataserviceversion version is 2.0.

```xml
<FunctionImport Name ="<some_func>" m:HttpMethod="GET" ReturnType="<string>">
   <Parameter Name="timeIN" Type="Edm.Time" Precision="0" Mode="In" />
</FunctionImport>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give Edm.time type in URL of abap gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004177/how-to-give-edm-time-type-in-url-of-abap-gateway)

Comment: No, tried: `/func(time=‘PT11H00M00S’)`.Doesn’t work and it raises an error /iwcor/cx_ds_uri_syntax_error

Comment: Are to trying to pass it as a key to an Entity or pass it as a variable to a function import?

Comment: Also which version of OData are you using.... The defination of the entity or function import from $metadata will help me answer this if you can post it here

Comment: @Shiva Edited the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is:
`func_imp_ex?timeIN=time'PT18H31M41S'`

Needed to prefix the string with the word key 'time'